# Azure powershell installed by cannot be accessed

Tags: powershell, azure

I have installed azure powershell using Microsoft Web Platform Installer 5.0.
 But I am not able to  find the azure powershell. I checked in porgrams
(x86), but couldn't find it .. What might be the problem?
 Please help as soon as posible

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4):

For anyone reading this:
I often experienced the same. I check the start menu after the installation of Azure Powershell via Web Platform Installer and there is nothing. In my opinion, the WPI only installs the cmdlets, no executable. WPI installs the cmdlets in this folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell

It is very important that you reboot your machine after the successful installation. You might even have to reboot during the installation if WPI tells you to and then restart the WPI until its completely finished.

After a reboot the cmdlets should be available in your normal Powershell.exe. Check if they are available by using:

```
Get-Command *Azure*
```

or

```
Get-Module *Azure*
```

I got frustrated by this several times and thats why I composed a blog post that explains the installation of Azure Powershell via WPI.

http://manuelmeyer.net/2016/05/azure-tip-1-installing-azure-powershell-using-the-web-platform-installer/

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to find a "Microsoft Azure PowerShell" shortcut in your Start Menu:

> C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft
>   Azure.

The shortcut points to:

> C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoExit
>   -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ServiceManagement\Azure\Services\ShortcutStartup.ps1"

Answer (score 1):

I also could not see Azure Powershell when I searched for power on start. But when I opened Windows powershell and ran command 
    `Get-Command *Azure*`,
I could see all cmdlets and was able to run all the Azure commands I wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

try downloading it from https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell. Powershell comes as standalone installer also

Comment: I am unable to access cmdlets.. What might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Download the publish settings file from the following link:
https://manage.windowsazure.com/publishsettings

In windows powershell ISE, run the following command to import the publish settings file:

```
Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile "D:\publish.publishsettings"
```

Run the following command to get all your subscriptions:

```
Get-AzureSubscription
```

Thus you can use windows Posershell to run the Azure powershell commandlets.